# Azure: Creating public ip address with Python

Tags: python, azure, networking, sdk, ip

I'm trying to create a public ip address in Azure with the Python SDK and I can't figure out why am I getting an error.
Here's my code :

```
netclient.public_ip_addresses.create_or_update('testgrp','testsdknic',{'location':'uksouth','sku':'standard','public_ip_allocation_method':'dynamic','public_ip_address_version':'ipv4'})
```

And this is the error I get :

```
SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have tried several things but while I'm succeeding in creating a network interface, I can't create the public IP.
Could anyone provide me with some guidance here please ?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, it caused by the property `sku` of the public IP address, it's the string, but a [`PublicIPAddressSku`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_12_01.models.publicipaddresssku?view=azure-python). So the code you need to change into this:

```
netclient.public_ip_addresses.create_or_update('testgrp','testsdknic',{'location':'uksouth',
'sku':{'name': 'standard'},'public_ip_allocation_method':'static','public_ip_address_version':'ipv4'})
```

And watch out, when you use the `standard` for the public IP address, then it should be in the `static` allocation method.

Comment: You've nailed it ! thanks. I must confess that I have a real hard time understanding Microsoft doc. The AWS Boto3 one is so much clearer ! Anyway thanks for that.